# Wifi connected but no internet access

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I'm using Xubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10, both on dedicated hard drives, but on the same laptop. I'm having problems connecting to my local WiFi network when using Linux. The situation is illustrated on this image

[Situation in local wifi network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNmX8.png)

The trouble appears only when trying to connect to the extended network, which runs 5 GHz. Although the signal strength is fine and all the other devices are connected and can access the internet (including the same laptop running Windows), there's no internet connection on Linux. Also, there's no problem when connected to other networks using 5 GHz band.

My wifi interface:

```
ifconfig: wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 fe80::2043:8909:71aa:8d53  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 44:1c:a8:e3:9e:f9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 29284  bytes 35527090 (35.5 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 19565  bytes 2228339 (2.2 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

ip routing:

```
    ip route show:
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.101 metric 600
```

When I try to ping local gateway

```
ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
18 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 17369ms
```

Detailed wireless information

```
sudo iwlist scan:
wlp2s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 98:DE:D0:28:87:2E
                    Channel:40
                    Frequency:5.2 GHz (Channel 40)
                    Quality=57/70  Signal level=-53 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"wifi_EXT"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 80ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00134D6973747220456C656769616E75735F455854
                    IE: Unknown: 01088C129824B048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 030128
                    IE: Unknown: 3C04011B2809
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A6E0016FF00000001000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1628070400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: 0B05030008127A
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4300000000
                    IE: Unknown: 200103
                    IE: Unknown: 0706444520241310
                    IE: Unknown: BF0C2000C031FEFF2401FEFF2401
                    IE: Unknown: C005012A00FEFF
```

Strangely, I receive some output from mtr 8.8.8.8. The packet loss of 80 % seems rather suspicious.

[mtr 8.8.8.8 link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g90bw.png)

I can see the device's IP from the WiFi extender's configuration, but there's no answer when I try to ping it. **EDIT** In fact, there are responses, but after a long time, see below.

I tried disabling IPv6 as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/653727), but it didn't help. I also replaced the */etc/resolv.conf* suggested [hear](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028814), which didn't help either. Anyway I think that this issue not linked to wrong DNS, since I can't even ping my gateway.

**EDIT**

Here is some hardware info about my wireless adapter

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: 44:1c:a8:e3:9e:f9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.35.177.61 firmware=01-ea662a8c ip=192.168.0.101 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:147 memory:dd800000-dd807fff memory:dd400000-dd7fffff
```

I also checked `dmesg` after pinging local gateway and I noticed this output, that doesn't show up on other networks:

```
dmesg
[28600.703766] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-52
```

In Wireshark, I can see standard network traffic, e.g. the router is asking for laptop's mac address and the laptop answers. I also tried once again pinging the laptop from other device and there is a response, although after a very long delay (30 seconds and more, the first requests don't appear in Wireshark).

Only request packets show up when I ping from the laptop, there are no responses at all.

```
wireshark – 192.168.0.101 192.168.0.1   ICMP    98  Echo (ping) request  id=0x0ba8, seq=1/256, ttl=64 (no response found!)
```

Comment: Guess: You are using some hardware where the driver isn't fully working. Please edit question with the kind of hardware and what you driver you are using. Also have a look in `dmesg` after the ping/mtr, and see if you can see anything suspicious. Use tcpdump or wireshark to see what kinds of packets you get from the WLAN.

Comment: @dirkt Thanks for suggestions, I edited the question.

Comment: Can you check if you've got Internet access from your phone working as a hotspot on the 2.4GHz range? Just for a few minutes, can you activate the hotspot, connect your Linux to it and check? If so, maybe your WiFi card needs indeed a new driver on the Linux partition for the 5GHz range. If not, it may be something else.

Comment: Googling for the error message finds [this](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/2087), with similar symptoms. People tried to upgrade the firmware, and also the kernel to get a newer version of the driver, and in same cases that seemed to have helped.

Comment: @Didier Linux partion has internet access when connected to my phone's hotspot on both 2.4GHz and 5Ghz range.

Comment: Maybe your extender is limited in the number of devices it can cater to?

Comment: @Didier unfortunately that's not the case, same problem even if Linux is the only device connected. In fact, I have two extenders of the same type and non of them works

Comment: Which security protocol have you enabled on your repeaters. WPA2-PSK is the current standard of choice for home networks, and probably enforced at kernel level by Linux now.

Comment: @dirkt I'm using kernel `5.3.0-46-generic`, the driver obtained from `lshw` is `driverversion=7.35.177.61 firmware=01-ea662a8c`. Unfortunately I don't know, whether the firmware version is up to date or not, do you have any thought on this?

Comment: @Didier Both extenders repeat signal from WPA/WPA2-PSK secured WiFi router, therefore both of them are also using this protocol.

Comment: One thing you can do is tell your WiFi adapter on Linux to forget your repeaters' SSIDs, reboot Linux and make it discover your WiFi network again. Once that's done, can also check if your repeaters' SSIDs are at the top of the list of favorites WiFi networks, and if Linux treats them as private networks, not public ones.

Comment: @Didier I tried that several times, after forgetting the extender's SSID and rebooting, the network is not in favorites since it's been forgotten. There's no information if the network is private or public, what difference would it make?

Comment: If you've set the network to private, Linux should not only see it, unless you've hidden the SSID, but it should treat it as a secure network, as opposed to public hotspots at McDonald's or anywhere else, and there'd be no reason no to connect to it. After forgetting your network, you must point Linux at it, enter your password, check that the security protocol you choose on Linux is the same as that of your network, and it should be OK. If not, there would be an error message.

Comment: @Didier after forgetting the network, I entered the password and Linux is connected again. Nevertheless, there's still no internet access. The only error that I've encountered is the one from `dmesg`, mentioned in my question.

Comment: Looks like you've got a Broadcom WiFi adapter on your PC, and the driver needs an update in Linux. Can you plug it to your router with an Ethernet cable and try a "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade" in Terminal?

Comment: @Didier There wasn't any new update available for the driver, anyway I reinstalled it but there's still no internet access

Comment: Have you tried the method described here (https://itsfoss.com/fix-no-wireless-network-ubuntu/), with the Xubuntu ISO? Push come to shove, you can boot from Windows to download a new ISO.